# Merge documents by fields

Tags: arangodb

I have two types of docs. Main docs and additional info for it.

```
{
 "id": "371"
 "name": "Mike",
 "location": "Paris"
},
{
 "id": "371-1",
 "age": 20,
 "lastname": "Piterson"
}
```

I need to merge them by `id`, to get result doc. The result should look like:

```
{
 "id": "371"
 "name": "Mike",
 "location": "Paris"
 "age": 20,
 "lastname": "Piterson"
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? You can merge objects with [`MERGE()`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/aql/functions-document.html#merge), but what exactly are you trying to do/what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`COLLECT / INTO`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/aql/functions-string.html#split), [`SPLIT()`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/aql/functions-string.html#split), and [`MERGE()`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/aql/functions-document.html#merge):

```
FOR doc IN collection
    COLLECT id = SPLIT(doc.id, '-')[0] INTO groups
    RETURN MERGE(MERGE(groups[*].doc), {id})
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "371",
    "location": "Paris",
    "name": "Mike",
    "lastname": "Piterson",
    "age": 20
  }
]
```

This will:

1. Split each `id` attribute at any `-` and return the first part
2. Group the results into sepearate arrays (`groups`)
3. Merge #1: Merge all objects into one
4. Merge #2: Merge the `id` into the result

See [REMOVE & INSERT or REPLACE](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/aql/operations.html) for write operations.

Comment: Nice solution. You could write `FOR group IN groups RETURN group.doc` as `groups[*].doc` to make it little easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer